# soapui same username and password for authentication with all rest resources

Tags: rest, authentication, soapui

I have a Rest Project generated from a WADL, that contains tens of resources. The whole API domain requires authentication (using the same username and password for every resource): how do I share the credentials among all the resources?

So far I managed to set the username and password for each request (by using the *Auth* button at the bottom of the request window), but this means I have to set the credentials for each resources I'm going to query.

I found that the "service" entry in the project tree has a "Service Viewer" where, inside the *Service Endpoints* tab, I can enter username and password, but these do not seem to be used anywhere in my requests.

Comment: Can you show where the credentials are added a screen shot if possible? Hope you are talking about request properties only. Have you clicked on Assign button which is present on service tab and still not applied?

Comment: I have the same problem and I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Any thing that needs to be Shared can be set as properties at different levels.

1. Project level properties
2. Testsuite level properties
3. Testcase level properties 
   As per your requirement it seems like you want to share the credentials for all resources in the project so you can define it at **Project level** 
   Below Screen shot will explain better:
   [image]

You can refer these properties in the UserName and Password **Textbox** as 
**${#Project#UserName}**
**${#Project#Password}**

If you are wondering that password field is showing dots so relax SoapUI will take care of it,although I could not test it but below is the screen shot of my Project XML file.
[image]

I hope this will help and should work fine.

Comment: It works, but you still need to compile the basic auth for each request.